# when i run my code they tell me "int" objext is not callable on line 4

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def fdPt(f, eps):
    index = 5.0
    for i in range(57):
        if f(index) - index < eps:
            return guess
        else:
            index = f(index)
    return index
```

plse help i've tried all i can, am just a beginner

Comment: f is not callable. You should give us more code.

Comment: check the order of the arguments, looks like you're calling it as `fdPt(eps, f)`

Comment: Just show us like 3 lines leading up to the call to this function...or print the types of `f` and `eps`

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing an example of what `f` is before it is passed into your function, it seems like you might be treating it like a sequence object, and trying to index into it:

```
if f(index) - index < eps:
```

... might want to be:

```
if f[index] - index < eps:
```

This assumes `f` is a list, tuple, string, or some other indexable object.

The way you are treating it right now wants to use `f` like a callable (function, method, class constructor, ...)

To help with checking your objects, try printing the type of `f`:

```
def fdPt(f, eps):
    print f, type(f)
```

Comment: f is a function of one argument that returns a float

Comment: But according to your traceback, `f` is an int, not a function object.